# How can I justify that the function is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I have this function:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2(\ln x)^3} \ , \ x\in(0,\infty)$$

I have to show that is measurable but I don't know to do it.

I know that is continuous a.e. but I can't say anything with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to check the set $E(f<a)=\{x\in E: f(x) < a\}$ is measurable.
Here $E = (0,\infty), a>0$. Clearly the set $E(f<a)$ is open, it is measurable.

Comment: Why is it measurable? Because it is open?

Comment: $f$ is measurable if and only if the primitive image of open set is measurable, that is $E(f<a)$. You can write it with some union of open sets on line $R$, the open sets on $R$ is measurable.